# What is the lifecycle of the methods for a python Django DetailView?

Tags: python, django

When you write a view that extends Django's `DetailView` you can override the various methods such as `get_queryset()`, `get_object()` and `get_context_data()`

I'm having difficulty in `get_context_data` in reading the 'object' attribute. Specifically it seems to exist, but is class 'object':

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(SectionTextDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if object:
      print (str(object))
      ## in reality try some logic with the object here
    else:
      print("very bad!")
  return context
```

(this prints "")

I suspect that `get_object()` is called after `get_context_data()`? Is that true?

My overall question is - what is the lifecycle (the order of the evaluation) of the methods in a `View` class, specifically the `DetailView`?

I looked at the reference entry for `DetailView` and `SingleObjectMixin` in the Django documentation and it doesn't seem to explicitly mention this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't define anything called `object` here. The only thing with that name is the built-in Python type.

You should probably be using `self.object`. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py#L109), `get_object` is called immediately on calling `get()`, so it should be available straight away.

Comment: yes, I realised that error after I pasted the code in.

The order of evaluation is get_object() then get_context_data(). Also contrary to what is seemingly implied in the django documentation, get_queryset() is never called in a DetailView, which would make sense, as we are dealing with a single object and not a alist.

Comment: @scot `get_queryset()` *will* be called, in the [`get_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/views/generic/detail.py#L21) method.

Comment: probably wasn't being called in my stack because i overrode get_object to just use objects.get(pk) then without calling super()